# Ширина и высота Canvas в HTML5

Tags: html, canvas

Можно ли исправить ширину и высоту элемента canvas HTML5?

Обычный способ следующий:

`<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>`

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938346/7394871) от участника  [@Dustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596215/dustin).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938346/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Элемент DOM холста имеет свойства `.height` и `.width`, которые соответствуют атрибутам `height = "…"` и `width = "…".` Установите для них числовые значения в коде JavaScript, чтобы изменить размер холста. Например:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width  = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

Обратите внимание, что это очищает холст, хотя вы должны выполнить `ctx.clearRect (0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);` для обработки тех браузеров, которые не полностью очищают холст. Вам нужно будет перерисовать любой контент, который вы хотели отображать после изменения размера.

**Обратите внимание**, что высота и ширина являются логическими размерами холста, используемыми для рисования, и отличаются от атрибутов CSS `style.height` и `style.width`. Если вы не установите атрибуты CSS, внутренний размер холста будет использоваться в качестве размера его отображения; если вы установите атрибуты CSS, и они будут отличаться от размеров холста, ваш контент будет масштабирован в браузере. Например:

```
// Создайте холст с размытым пиксельным увеличением (zoom-in)
// с каждым нарисованным пикселем холста, отображаемым на экране примерно как 2x2
canvas.width  = 400;
canvas.height = 300; 
canvas.style.width  = '800px';
canvas.style.height = '600px';
```

Посмотрите этот  пример холста, увеличенного в 4 раза.

```js
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth   = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
ctx.fillStyle   = '#eff';

ctx.fillRect(  10.5, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.strokeRect( 10.5, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.fillRect(   40, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.strokeRect( 40, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.fillRect(   70, 10, 20, 20 );
ctx.strokeRect( 70, 10, 20, 20 );

ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
ctx.strokeRect( 10.5, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.strokeRect( 40, 10.5, 20, 20 );
ctx.strokeRect( 70, 10, 20, 20 );
```

```css
body { background:#eee; margin:1em; text-align:center }
canvas { background:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc; width:400px; height:160px }
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="40"></canvas>
<p>Показано, что повторное рисование тех же линий со сглаживанием не стирает старые линии со сглаживанием.</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939066/7394871) от участника  [@Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz).</sub>

Comment: Ну все, энциклопедия `canvas` объявляет день открытых дверей)) Было интересно, ждем следующих выпусков!

Comment: @Leonid мне тоже интересно, сравниваю с SVG :) как всё по разному... прямоугольник красится, строка(обводка) может быть отдельно от прямоугольника И эффект, что canvas может быть растянут до родительского контейнера в роли которого выступают стили CSS  Ну и ты подключайся, чтобы раскачать этот мертвый раздел - canvas

Comment: @Leonid вот интересно также -- строка в canvas обрезается на половину, как в SVG на границе холста?

Comment: Должно по идее, тут все так же, никакой разницы нет. Stroke по середине проходит, толщина условно на обе стороны идет. Другое поведение, вроде, можно настроить для замкнутых. Думаю, геометрия и пути все равно на базе SVG работают, вот только некоторых вещей вроде getTotalLength нет, почему то...